# BinaryFormatter doesn't serialize public fields when a class is inherited from Exception, why?

Tags: c#, .net

Could anyone explain to me why the below class inherited from Exception
doesn't serialize private fields?

Should I serialize the object manually when deriving from Exception?

```
[Serializable]
public class Test : Exception
{
  private int _errNo = 0;
  private string _msg = String.Empty;

  public int ErrNo
  {
    get { return _errNo; }
  }

  public string Msg
  {
    get { return _msg; }
  }

  public Test(int err, string msg)
  {
    _errNo = err;
    _msg = msg;
  }

  protected Test(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
    System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext kontekst)
    : base(info, kontekst)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know any serializer that serializes private fields?

Comment: Public fields above which point to the adequate private fields are correctly serialized without Exception class.

Comment: @maxlego Yes, `BinarySerializer`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Exception` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) implements [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx), which allows `Exception` to override how it is serialized. Since `Exception`'s `GetObjectData` implementation does not use reflection to determine which fields to serialise, you need to override that and explicitly list any new fields yourself. You then also need to restore those fields in your constructor.